# jQuery .live function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Can somebody please tell me why this script is not working? It is supposed to work, but it doesn't, I am getting the id correctly, but Divs are not displaying properly. My idea is to display one div based on the click, and hide the other Divs.

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").live("click", function(){
    var idV = $(this).attr("id"); 
    alert(idV);
    $("#"+idV+"div").css("display","block");
    return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="solution1">Solution 1</a>
<a href="#" id="solution2">Solution 2</a>
<a href="#" id="solution3">Solution 3</a>
<a href="#" id="solution4">Solution 4</a>
<br />

<div id="solution1" style="display:none;">Solution 1</div>
<div id="solution2" style="display:none;">Solution 2</div>
<div id="solution3" style="display:none;">Solution 3</div>
<div id="solution4" style="display:none;">Solution 4</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your div ids are wrong.
Try:

```
<div id="solution1div" style="display:none;">Solution 1</div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="solution1" style="display:none;">Solution 1</div>
```

Edit:

**[JSBIN: Preview](http://jsbin.com/idoje/)**

**[JSBIN: Source Code](http://jsbin.com/idoje/edit)**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="solution1">Solution 1</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" id="solution2">Solution 2</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" id="solution3">Solution 3</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" id="solution4">Solution 4</a> 
<br /> 

<div> 
<div id="solution1div" style="display:none;">Solution 1</div> 
<div id="solution2div" style="display:none;">Solution 2</div> 
<div id="solution3div" style="display:none;">Solution 3</div> 
<div id="solution4div" style="display:none;">Solution 4</div> 
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("a").live("click", function(){ 
var idV = $(this).attr("id");  

$("#"+idV+"div").siblings().hide(); 
$("#"+idV+"div").show(); 

return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ghommey... it did work for me.. but when i click on a div, it gets displayed properly, and when the second link is clicked, the first DIV's is still visible.. how do i hide the div of the links which are not clicked ??

Comment: Thanks Ghommey.. But my top links are also getting hidden when clicking on it ??

Comment: You have to add another div surrounding the solution divs like I did in my post.

Answer (score 1):

mmmm the error is actually there man..

see:

```
$("#"+idV+".div").css("display","block");
```

change it to:

```
$("div#"+idV).css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing ID attributes. IDs need to be unique to a document.

You can't have anchors and divs with the same ID.

Comment: yeah i was so dumb to use the same attributes for the links and div's. Even after me changing the id to title, i am still not able to view the div's on click...